# how to specify tastypie always return json data

Tags: django, tastypie

my resource code is

```
class MessageResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Message.objects.all()
        resource_name = "message"
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
    def determine_format(self, request):
        return "application/json"
```

If I get the message resource without any authentication info, the response is

```
401 UNAUTHORIZED
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Mon, 19 Nov 2012 15:36:28 GMT";
Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2";
```

instead of html, I want to get the JSON response. Actually, I want to know how to specify tastypie only send back JSON response in any cases?

I want to get the JSON response like

`{ "code": "401", "message": "Unauthorized" }`

Is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

This is valid HTTP response. There is no JSON 401 response specified nowhere and there is no need for tastypie to come up with any default one.

If you have such need, simply wrap your API with proper middleware.

**Update: How to setup middleware**

Fisrt, read through [middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs).

Then, I think you will need to implement `process_response` method on your new middleware class, and do whatever you need to do with response depending on its [status code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code).

Don't forget to add your middleware class to `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: thanks,if I want to get response like { "code": "401", "message": "Unauthorized" }, what's middleware I should use?

Comment: Updated my answer with proper documentation links.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply in your `settings` file do `TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS = ['json']`.